# One method, multiple rest paths

Tags: regex, rest, path, annotations, resteasy

Is it possible to set multiple `@Path` annotation on the same REST method in Java?

Obviously I have tried this however it did not work it failed to compile, but is there some way to do this? Perhaps vie the regular expression?

I am using resteasy if that helps.

My methods look like this (pseudo code below):

```
@Path("/project/{projecID}/car/{carID}/carService/{carserviceID}/engine/{engineID}")
public Engine getCarEngin(@PathParam("projecID") projectID, @PathParam("carID") carID, @PathParam("carserviceID") carserviceID, @PathParam{engineID}){
    // return engine based on the id
}

@Path("/project/{projecID}/bus/{busID}/busService/{busserviceID}/engine/{engineID}")
public Engine getBusEngin(@PathParam("projecID") projectID, @PathParam("busID") busID, @PathParam("carserviceID") carserviceID, @PathParam{engineID}){
    // return engine based on the id
}
```

So the method is the same, the logic is the same but so I would like to unite this under one method but keep the two paths to it.

Comment: What does happen to `projectID`, `carID`, and `busID`? Are they not needed by the methods?

Comment: They are but I didnt put the logic for that as it is not really important for my question, or now that I have give this a more thought it actually might be important. Would that actually makes this impossible as I would have to have 2 sets of parameters in the method?

Comment: But they are important for the signatures of the questions. Do both methods really take the same arguments?

Comment: yes they take the same arguments. The differences is that the id's represent different objects like it is given above.

Comment: But the `QPathParam` must differ between the two methods. Please post the complete method signatures.

Comment: The full method params have been added. I am actually using the interface for the annotations and the implementation is only different in the name of the method since what the implemenation is just String, String, String, String for the 4 ids

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to set multiple @Path annotation on the same REST
>   method in Java?

As you have discovered  That's not possible.

```
Perhaps vie the regular expression?
```

You could do it with regular expressions, but that would just introduce a lot of unnecessary complexity. It would also reduce the readability of your `@Path`-annotations. IMHO, don't use regular expressions for this.

Perhaps you can do something like this:

```
enum VehicleType {
    BUS, CAR
}


@Path("/project/{projecID}/{vehicleType}/{vehicleID}/service/{serviceID}/engine/{engineID}")
public Engine getEngine(@PathParam("projecID") projectID, 
    @PathParam("vehicleType") VehicleType vehicleType,  
    @PathParam("vehicleID") vehicleID, @PathParam("serviceID") serviceID, 
    @PathParam("engineID"} engineID){

    // return engine based on the id
}
```

Comment: but just for the interest if I wanted to go with the regnext, what would that look like, the path annotation that is?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.4.Final/userguide/html_single/index.html#_Path_and_regular_expression_mappings